# Convert seconds into 0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 0 secs

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to convert my seconds into the numbers of hours, days,... contained into my time.

I have tried the following request ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bf2fd/30943)):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR((1670857661 || ' second')::interval, 'YYYY" years" MM" mons "DD" days "HH24" hours "MI" mins "SS" secs"')
```

**Current Output**:

```
0000 years 00 mons 00 days 464127 hours 07 mins 41 secs
```

**Expected output**:

```
54 years 8 mons 12 days 10 hours 51 mins 12 secs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `justify_interval()`

```
select justify_interval(make_interval(secs => 1670857661));
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/RefHefHk)